# Socket.setPerformancePreferences

Tags: java, sockets

Can anyone help me get more information on what this method `Socket.setPerformancePreferences(int connectionTime, int latency, int bandwidth)` does and how it affects the Socket performance ? The Java API information is very short and introductory only.  Any links that has some examples and some discussion on this will be very helpful. I tried googling it but could find very helpful info either.

Answer (score 14):

Here's the source code for this method in 1.6 of Oracle's distribution:

```
public void setPerformancePreferences(int connectionTime,
                                      int latency,
                                      int bandwidth)
{
/* Not implemented yet */
}
```

So it does nothing.

Comment: It will be not even being executed after JIT

Comment: By default, this method does nothing, unless it is overridden in a sub-class.

Comment: Same @ Sun JDK 1.8

Comment: Same in OpenJDK 11.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setPerformancePreferences(int connectionTime,
                                      int latency,
                                      int bandwidth)
```

> Sets performance preferences for this socket. Sockets use the TCP/IP
>   protocol by default. Some implementations may offer alternative
>   protocols which have different performance characteristics than
>   TCP/IP. This method allows the application to express its own
>   preferences as to how these tradeoffs should be made when the
>   implementation chooses from the available protocols.
>
> Performance preferences are described by three integers whose values
>   indicate the relative importance of short connection time, low
>   latency, and high bandwidth. The absolute values of the integers are
>   irrelevant; in order to choose a protocol the values are simply
>   compared, with larger values indicating stronger preferences. Negative
>   values represent a lower priority than positive values. If the
>   application prefers short connection time over both low latency and
>   high bandwidth, for example, then it could invoke this method with the
>   values (1, 0, 0). If the application prefers high bandwidth above low
>   latency, and low latency above short connection time, then it could
>   invoke this method with the values (0, 1, 2).
>
> Invoking this method after this socket has been connected will have no
>   effect.
>
> Parameters: connectionTime - An int expressing the relative importance
>   of a short connection time latency - An int expressing the relative
>   importance of low latency bandwidth - An int expressing the relative
>   importance of high bandwidth Since:
>   1.5

Source:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setPerformancePreferences(int, int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setPerformancePreferences%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

Note however if you coding for Android, that in Eclipse, the android documentation tells me the following about this method:

```
public void setPerformancePreferences (int connectionTime, int latency, int bandwidth)
```

> Since: API Level 1  Sets performance preferences for connectionTime,
>   latency and bandwidth.
>
> This method does currently nothing.
>
> Parameters connectionTime  the value representing the importance of a
>   short connecting time.  latency  the value representing the importance
>   of low latency.  bandwidth  the value representing the importance of
>   high bandwidth.

Note the line "This method does currently nothing." I'm not sure if this is universally true for all android devices, if this documentation is out dated or what, but according to it this method is technically present but unimplemented on the Android platform.